# Can pm2 run an 'npm start' script

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, pm2

Is there a way for pm2 to run an npm start script or do you just have to run `pm2 start app.js`

So in development

```
npm start
```

Then in production with pm2 you would run something like

```
pm2 start 'npm start'
```

There is an equivalent way to do this in `forever`:

```
forever start -c "npm start" ./
```

Comment: This is extension to Answer given by Dhaval 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37775318/4828326

1. First add pm2 to your package.json
2. For development mode, update your package json script like this:

        "pm2:dev": "node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-dev start npm -- start",

Answer (score 858, accepted):

PM2 now supports npm start:

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

To assign a name to the PM2 process, use the `--name` option:

```
pm2 start npm --name "app name" -- start
```

Comment: How can you set a name for the process when using this command? I tried using `--name "app"` but it just set it to npm.

Comment: pm2 start npm --name "Your APP Name" -- start

Comment: Anyone know how to set `npm start` in the process file?

Comment: How comes I got "stopped" status when I try this? my start script looks like this `"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon dist-prod/server.js"`

Comment: What does the double dash do in this command? I was trying to look it up in the docs and in the cli `--help` readout for pm2 but couldn't find the explanation.

Comment: ah, I think I found the answer to my question. It's not a pm2 or npm thing, it seems to be a *nix way of saying "I'm done giving command options and want to start passing arguments": https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash

Comment: In theory, could `npm` be substituted for any other node-based bin module installed globally, and passed whatever arguments that module needs after ` -- ` the same way?

Comment: For me it throws an error in the logs:

 C:\DEV\NODEJS\NPM.CMD:1
0|weally   | (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { :: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
0|weally   |                                                               ^
0|weally   | 
0|weally   | SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
0|weally   |     at new Script (vm.js:74:7)

similar issue here: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3652

Comment: You can also use it as ```pm2 start --name "App Name" npm -- start```

Comment: it didn't work in my case. Initially it ran but when I ran pm2 list,  I got the status 'stopped'

Comment: -- signifies the end of a command. So npm is the actual command and start is the args here.

Comment: To run PM2 with `npm start` method and to give it a name
`pm2 start npm --name "your_app_name" -- start`

Comment: the two slashes what exactly are doing?

Comment: @laukik-patel , What is the meaning of the two dashes " -- " in "pm2 npm -- start"?

Comment: I'm never gonna remember how to put these -- two times... I keep coming to this answer for years now.

Answer (score 175):

Those who are using a configuration script like a `.json` file to run the pm2 process can use `npm start` or any other script like this -

**my-app-pm2.json**

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "my-app",
            "script": "npm",
            "args" : "start"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then simply -

```
pm2 start my-app-pm2.json
```

**Edit** - To handle the use case when you have this configuration script in a parent directory and want to launch an app in the sub-directory then use the `cwd` attribute.

Assuming our app is in the sub-directory `nested-app` relative to this configuration file then -

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "my-nested-app",
            "cwd": "./nested-app",
            "script": "npm",
            "args": "start"
        }
    ]
}
```

More detail [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2003).

Comment: how does this work if I want to run the start npm script from a parent folder?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I assume you're asking *How to run* **npm start** *from outside the project directory?* .

Comment: I'm using the configuration script to run multiple node apps that are in sub-folders. The package.json with the `start` script information is in one of them. See this gist: https://gist.github.com/gianpaj/04c5680a8275616aac5e46374e07f673
When I run this it doesn't know where `npm` should run from. Thx

Comment: @GianfrancoP. You can use the `cwd` attribute. Check my edited answer :)

Comment: I tried to use sudo npm and it shows access error to create a directory tough I have given all the permission to user as root and also running pm2 command as `sudo pm2 start config.json`

Comment: How to start multi `npm start` with `pm2`? when I add call this another one will display error

Comment: How can i run something like `npm run server` or `npm run proxy`? Would change `args` with `server` be enough?

Answer (score 92):

To use `npm run`

`pm2 start npm --name "{app_name}" -- run {script_name}`

Comment: Indeed, I agree with @Adiii , given that it can be run as an npm script, it just doesn't get any better than that!

Answer (score 57):

I needed to run a specific npm script on my app in pm2 (for each env)
In my case, it was when I created a staging/test service

The command that worked for me (the args must be forwarded that way):

```
pm2 start npm --name "my-app-name" -- run "npm:script"
```

examples:

```
pm2 start npm --name "myApp" -- run "start:test"

pm2 start npm --name "myApp" -- run "start:staging"

pm2 start npm --name "myApp" -- run "start:production"
```

Hope it helped

Comment: notice that there is a space in between  "-- run". Space needs to be there else you will get invalid option run.

Answer (score 52):

Yes. Use `pm2 start npm --no-automation --name {app name} -- run {script name}`. It works. The `--no-automation` flag is there [because without it PM2 will not restart your app when it crashes.](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1934)

Comment: Do you have any idea how to use this flag inside of the ecosystem.js configuration file?

Comment: UPDATE:
Okay I found it you need to specify "automation": false.

Comment: @twigg `pm2 --help | grep 'no-autom'` returns one line for me in version 1.0.2

Answer (score 46):

you need to provide app name here like myapp

```
pm2 start npm --name {appName} -- run {script name}
```

you can check it by

```
pm2 list
```

you can also add time

```
pm2 restart "id" --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS'
```

or

```
pm2 restart "id" --time
```

you can check logs by

```
pm2 log "id"
```

or

```
pm2 log "appName"
```

to get logs for all app

```
pm2 logs
```

Comment: Hi, @pharaj_ali, can you explain this part `-- run {script name}` ? I can't found it on the pm2 documentation. I've read on the edit history of your answer and I've found this interesting edit: `in case of different script name use run with script name and in case of start script no need to add run`. If I understand, using `run {script name}` is for multiple script and with only `npm start` it's more relevant to use `pm2 start npm --name {appName} -- start`? Plus I don't understand why the space between `--`and `start/run` any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Hi @YohanW.Dunon 
yes you are right
while running npm, if we are using start script then we don't need to use run there
```npm start```
but in case of other script we use run like 
```npm run {script name}```

for the case of space between ```--```, I think it is simply the way they use (not sure)
let me know if you find answer for that

Answer (score 37):

I wrote shell script below (named `start.sh`).
Because my `package.json` has `prestart` option.
So I want to run `npm start`.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/project
npm start
```

Then, start `start.sh` by pm2.

```
pm2 start start.sh --name appNameYouLike
```

Comment: That's nice. Unfortunately this doesn't work when using the `startOrRestart` command.

Comment: @xpepermint just use the -f flag at the end. It forces a start. (i.e it'll restart if already started)

Answer (score 20):

Yes we can, now pm2 support npm start, --name to species app name.

```
pm2 start npm --name "app" -- start
```

Comment: This is the answer which really helped me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 17):

You can change directory to your project

```bash
cd /my-project
```

then run

```bash
pm2 start "npm run start" \\ run npm script from your package.json
```

or

```bash
pm2 start "yarn start"
```

read more [here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/)

Answer (score 14):

See to enable clustering:

```
pm2 start npm --name "AppName" -i 0 -- run start
```

What do you think?

Comment: what does the `-i 0` do?

Comment: Start maximum processes depending on available CPUs (cluster mode)

Answer (score 12):

If you use PM2 via node modules instead of globally, you'll need to set `interpreter: 'none'` in order for the above solutions to work. Related docs [here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/using-transpilers-with-pm2).

In `ecosystem.config.js`:

```
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'myApp',
      script: 'yarn',
      args: 'start',
      interpreter: 'none',
    },
  ],
```

Answer (score 10):

`pm2 start npm --name "custom_pm2_name" -- run prod`

```
"scripts": {
    "prod": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./src/index.js"
  }
```

This worked for me when the others didnt

Comment: Thank you so much, Luke. Especially appreciate that you posted your script alongside, no more guessing which "start" is which :) This should be rated higher, finally something that just works.

Answer (score 10):

**For the normal user**

PM2 now supports npm start:

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

To assign a name to the PM2 process, use the "--name" option:

```
pm2 start npm --name "your desired app name" -- start
```

**For the root user**

```
sudo pm2 start npm -- start
```

To assign a name to the PM2 process, use the "--name" option:

```
sudo pm2 start npm --name "your desired app name" -- start
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Absolutely you can do it very efficiently by using a pm2 config (json) file with elegance.

#### package.json file (containing below example scripts)

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently npm:server npm:dev",
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "node ./scripts/build.js",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src server",
    "shivkumarscript": "ts-node -T -P server/tsconfig.json server/index.ts"
  }
```

Suppose we want to run the script named as 'shivkumarscript' with pm2 utility. So, our pm2 config file should be like below, containing 'script' key with value as 'npm' and 'args' key with value as 'run '. Script name is 'shivkumarscript' in our case.

#### ecosystem.config.json file

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: "NodeServer",
            script: "npm",
            automation: false,
            args: "run shivkumarscript",
            env: {
                NODE_ENV: "development"
            },
            env_production: {
                NODE_ENV: "production"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Assuming that you have already installed Node.js, NPM and PM2 on your machine. Then below should be the command to start the application through pm2 which will in turn run the npm script (command line mentioned in your application's package.json file):

For production environment:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production --only NodeServer
```

For development environment:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --only NodeServer
```

...And Boooom! guys

Answer (score 4):

if anyone has to pass any other script with a name here's how to do it.

```
pm2 start "npm run dev" --name myAppName
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the space before start

```
pm2 start npm --[space]start
```

so the correct command is:

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

Answer (score 2):

### It's working fine on CentOS 7

**PM2 version 4.2.1**

let's take two scenarios:

**1. npm start** //server.js

```
pm2 start "npm -- start" --name myMainFile
```

**2. npm run main** //main.js

```
pm2 start "npm -- run main" --name myMainFile
```

Answer (score 2):

To run PM2 with `npm start` method and to give it a `name`, run this,
`pm2 start npm --name "your_app_name" -- start`

To run it by passing date-format for logs,
`pm2 start npm --name "your_name" --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS' -- start`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems that pm2 doesn't support the exact functionality you requested https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1317.

The alternative proposed is to use a `ecosystem.json` file [Getting started with deployment](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#getting-started-with-deployment) which could include setups for production and dev environments. However, this is still using `npm start` to bootstrap your app.

Comment: What do you mean by that? `However, this is still using npm start to bootstrap your app.` Can you actually run `npm start` using `pm2`?

Answer (score 1):

```
pm2 start ./bin/www
```

can running

if you wanna multiple server deploy
you can do that. instead of pm2 start npm -- start

Answer (score 1):

For my vite project on AWS EC2,

`pm2 start npm -- run dev --host` was only captured in the pm2 list but was not really running the `npm run dev --host`

I Had this error:

```
PM2        | 2023-09-03T02:36:50: PM2 log: Script /root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/npm had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
PM2        | 2023-09-03T02:37:01: PM2 log: App [npm:1] starting in -fork mode-
...
...
```

...So I swapped **npm** for **yarn**, so this worked in my case `pm2 start yarn -- dev --host` as it runs `yarn dev --host` ✅

Answer (score 0):

Now, You can use after:

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

Follow by https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1317#issuecomment-220955319

Comment: Can you expand your answer?  Advice from [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

for this first, you need to create a file run.js and paste the below code on that.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
//here npm.cmd for windows.for others only use npm
const workerProcess = spawn('npm.cmd', ['start']); 

  workerProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {  
      console.log('stdout: ' + data);  
   });  
 workerProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {  
      console.log('stderr: ' + data);  
   });  
 workerProcess.on('close', function (code) {  
      console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);  
   });
```

and run this file with pm2.

```
pm2 start run.js
```

- List item