# Start nodejs app that use cross-env with pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, server, pm2

I'm trying to start my nodejs app, the default cmd is the following :

```
pm2 start app.js
```

I can't do that because I use cross-env and the script as below:

```
"start": cross-env DOTENV_FILE=.env node build/app.js
```

So `npm run start` will launch the script above.

How can I serve my app using pm2 and the script above ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can pm2 run an 'npm start' script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579509/can-pm2-run-an-npm-start-script)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

or

```
pm2 start npm --name CrossApp -- run start
```

Hope this helps