# Can not start node process using pm2

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js and having difficulty  to demonize [this](https://github.com/FreeFeed/freefeed-server) app using pm2. 
The app works fine when I go to `/srv/myapp` and run `yarn start` but when I try to demonize it by going to `/srv/myapp` and run `pm2 start index.js`

I see that the process seem to have started:

```
[PM2] Starting /srv/myapp/index.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ user │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼──────┼──────────┤
│ index    │ 0  │ fork │ 14528 │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 16.0 MB   │ root │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴──────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

But the front end does not respond (instead I get `502 errors` and the node server does not listen on port `3000` as expected (`fuser 3000/tcp`
 returns no results).

What could be wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it work if you run "node index.js"?

Comment: No, `node index.js` causes `import bb from 'bluebird';SyntaxError: Unexpected token import `

Comment: I suspect that's the root of your problem. Are you using babel or anything? I couldn't find any documentation on `yarn start`, do you know if it's running a custom script to transpile ES6 javascript to ES5 that Node can then run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can pm2 run an 'npm start' script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579509/can-pm2-run-an-npm-start-script)

Comment: (`yarn start` is not the same as `pm2 start`)

Comment: @sdgluck good point. `pm2 start npm -- start` works for me!

Answer (score 3):

Check pm2 logs by command: `pm2 logs`
If there is no errors, than problem not with your app.

Answer (score 1):

`pm2` starts your app with node, one problem is it doesn't provide any logging or output like starting an app by other means (such as `node index.js` does), so it doesn't really let you know if there is anything going wrong.

I've always found it's a good idea to test your app by starting it with `node` before `pm2`.

Given `node index.js` causes the error: `import bb from 'bluebird';SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`, which makes it sound like you're using ES6 import feature, [not supported by Node by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634198/node-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import). I suspect Yarn is either enabling these features, or transpiling your ES6 code to ES5 for Node to run when you do the `yard start`, but I'm not familiar with Yarn to know.

It may be you're pointing at the wrong file, and there's a transpiled file `dist.js` (as an example) already created that Yarn is happily running with the opaque `start` command.

---

**Edit:** After looking at the source, it looks to be using [something called `babel-node`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node). See the [start script in the package.json](https://github.com/FreeFeed/freefeed-server/blob/stable/package.json):

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "babel-node index.js",
```

`pm2` doesn't know to run your index.js with this babel-node thing, and even if it did babel-node strongly recommends you do not use babel-node in production (which presumably you are doing with `pm2`):

> **Not meant for production use**
>   You should not be using babel-node in production. It is unnecessarily heavy, with high memory usage due to the cache being stored in memory. You will also always experience a startup performance penalty as the entire app needs to be compiled on the fly.
>
> Check out the example Node.js server with Babel for an idea of how to use Babel in a production deployment.

And there's also a note about ES6 module loading:

> **ES6-style module-loading may not function as expected**
>   Due to technical limitations ES6-style module-loading is not fully supported in >a babel-node REPL.

I'd strongly recommend you add a `build` script to produce a 'distribution' transpiled version with babel and deploy that!

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "babel-node index.js",
  "build": "babel index.js --out-file index-dist.js
```

Or something along those lines, and run `yarn build` (or `yarn run build`?) then `pm2 start index-dist.js`.

Comment: Yes, the app uses ES6 and babel. But the app does also run using `node start`. You can see the docs here: https://github.com/FreeFeed/freefeed-server . What do you suggest to demonize the app, if pm2 is not suitable here?

Comment: Also `node start pm2` yeilds: `module.js:540
    throw err;  Error: Cannot find module '/srv/myapp/pm2'`

Comment: `node start pm2` doesn't really make sense as there's  no pm2 javascript file in your app to run. `pm2` is a tool to run js like node is (and uses node). Using `node` to run `pm2` doesn't really work. See my edit.

Comment: Well, I add `"build": "babel index.js --out-file index-dist.js` to package.json scripts and now `yarn start index-dist.js` does start the app but `pm2 start index-dist.js` results in `script not found : /srv/myapp/index-dist.js`. How can I create that?

Comment: Is there an `index-dist.js` file created if you poke around the file system? It might be created in the root directory or something.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, I had not run `yarn run build`. But now when I run `pm2 start index-dist.js` the process starts but I still get 502 in browser.

Comment: What happens when you run `node index-dist.js`, it should display any errors that occur when you try connect with the browser.

Comment: I get `/srv/myapp/app/app.js:2
import http from 'http';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`