# How can I fix issues launching an app in PM2 on Windows?

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2, docusaurus

I am trying to run [Docusaurus](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/installation) on Windows Server 2016 with Node.js version 12.14.0 via PM2 on IIS10. I am using PM2 so I can have the apps restart after a server reboot. I have to admit now that today is the first time I have ever attempted anything with Node.js, so please bear with me.

This is [usually run](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/installation#running-the-development-server) by calling `npm run start` within the Docusaurus directory. When testing out Node.js and whether a 'Hello World' app would start on reboot of the server, I was using the `ecosystem.config.js` as suggested in the PM2 documentation. This called a javascript file like so.

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
      {
        name: "HelloWorld",
        script: "apps\\hello_world.js",
        instances: 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

This worked fine, but I could not find any documentation on how to run `npm start` from this file though (although I did try calling a separate batch file, which also didn't work). Then I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42619477/9164015) that I could call a JSON file that documented further options.

JSON configuration file:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "docs",
            "cwd": "apps\\docs",
            "script": "npm",
            "args": "start"
        },
        {
            "name": "HelloWorld",
            "script": "apps\\hello_world.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

The 'HelloWorld' script starts, but not the docs app.

pm2 report offers the following output:

```
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:20: PM2 log: App [docs:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:20: PM2 log: App [docs:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:20: PM2 log: App [docs:0] online
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:21: PM2 log: App [docs:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:21: PM2 log: App [docs:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:21: PM2 log: App [docs:0] online
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:21: PM2 log: App [docs:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:21: PM2 log: App [docs:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:21: PM2 log: App [docs:0] online
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:21: PM2 log: App [docs:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:21: PM2 log: App [docs:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:21: PM2 log: App [docs:0] online
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:22: PM2 log: App [docs:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:22: PM2 log: App [docs:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:22: PM2 log: App [docs:0] online
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:22: PM2 log: App [docs:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:22: PM2 log: App [docs:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:22: PM2 log: App [docs:0] online
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:22: PM2 log: App [docs:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2020-01-07T17:54:22: PM2 log: Script C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
```

Which brought me to [this](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4429) issue on GitHub. There doesn't seem to be a lot of activity on the issues there though, and there were historic occurrences of it too.

I think there may be something I am doing wrong with PM2 or there is a problem with it, because I cannot launch docs via the command line with PM2 either.

```sh
C:\Node JS\apps\docs>pm2 start npm --name "docs" -- start
```

Has anyone got any ideas on how I can get this to work or has tried to do anything similar? I would settle for an answer on:

- An alternative way to run Docusaurus on Windows Server.
- An alternative to using PM2.
- Any other ideas.

Apologies if I have rambled.

**EDIT:**

Output of `pm2 start ecosystem.json --only docs`

```sh
C:\Node JS>pm2 start ecosystem.json --only docs
[PM2][WARN] Applications docs not running, starting...
[PM2][ERROR] Process failed to launch EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\etc\.pm2\logs\docs-out.log'
```

The log it references is empty. The `docs-error.log` repeats the same error repeatedly, but has not been updated since last night. It was probably created from me trying out different syntaxes in the JSON file, but posting it anyway.

```sh
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:27:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD:1
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
```

Comment: What is the output of ```pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --only docs```?

Comment: Hi Vahid. Added the additional output as requested.

Comment: It would be nice for downvoters to comment as to why they have done so. I had not touched these technologies until yesterday, and I think the question shows a willingness to learn.

Comment: You need to ```run as administartor``` command line if the target is Windows platform. because your files are in C drive, and your current user has not enough permissions.

Comment: Hi Vahid, this was from an elevated administrator prompt, I'm afraid.

Comment: create ```C:\etc\.pm2\logs\docs-out.log``` manually and writable for all and see what's happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was actually how pm2 calls node via a batch file on Windows. If you call `npm-cli.js` directly with its full path the program will run without issue.

```json
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "docs",
            "cwd": "some_path_to\\apps\\docs",
            "script": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js",
            "args": "start",
            "exec_mode": "cluster",
            "instances": 1,
            "interpreter": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you solve your issue?

I run this under macos without problem, pm2 version is 5.1.0

please try: run "npm start" on your terminal

1. if the command execute and return to prompt. then you can not  run with pm2 in your way. you should try some other way.
2. if "npm start " not return to prompt. then you can.

Comment: Hi @JamesLiao, thanks for the reminder. I did resolve this and the issue is specific to Windows - I am going to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit cleaner and latest answer:

#### package.json file (containing below example scripts)

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently npm:server npm:dev",
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "node ./scripts/build.js",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src server",
    "shivkumarscript": "ts-node -T -P server/tsconfig.json server/index.ts"
  }
```

Suppose we want to run the script named as 'shivkumarscript' with pm2 utility. So, our pm2 config file should be like below, containing 'script' key with value as 'npm' and 'args' key with value as 'run '. Script name is 'shivkumarscript' in our case.

#### ecosystem.config.json file

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: "NodeServer",
            script: "npm",
            automation: false,
            args: "run shivkumarscript",
            env: {
                NODE_ENV: "development"
            },
            env_production: {
                NODE_ENV: "production"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Assuming that you have already installed Node.js, NPM and PM2 on your machine. Then below should be the command to start the application through pm2 which will in turn run the npm script (command line mentioned in your application's package.json file):

For production environment:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production --only NodeServer
```

For development environment:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --only NodeServer
```

...And Boooom! guys

Comment: You've misunderstood the issue, it is not about just being able to run a script via pm2.  It is a specific issue running npm via pm2 on Windows. You couldn't call npm directly via the system path as it calls a batch file and not the npm js script.

Comment: @Ash can you provide more detail on app\docs file? Also are you able to run docs normally in terminal using npm command?

Comment: I have already posted the solution for this a long time ago. Everything was specific to running from a pm2 configuration file on Windows.