# pm2 can't start script with :

Tags: node.js, pm2

I want to start my script with pm2 in Windows, but I get the error:
 `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`

my start script is `start:dev` and to run that I say: `pm2 start npm -- 'start:dev'`

my script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/src/index.js",
    "build": "tsc -p . && ncp productionenv ./dist/src/.env",
    "start:dev": "npm run build:dev",
    "build:dev": "nodemon src/index.ts --exec ts-node src/index.ts -e ts,graphql",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

Full err:

```
App [gateway:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | App [gateway:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | App [gateway:0] online
0|gateway  | C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD:1
0|gateway  | :: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
0|gateway  | ^
0|gateway  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
0|gateway  |     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
0|gateway  |     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
0|gateway  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
0|gateway  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
0|gateway  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
0|gateway  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
0|gateway  |     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
0|gateway  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
0|gateway  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
0|gateway  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
PM2        | App [gateway:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | Script C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579509/can-pm2-run-an-npm-start-script

Comment: @salman did exactly what they said `pm2 start npm --name "gateway" -- run "start:dev"` and still getting same error

Comment: i have used the same command and its working fine, check you package.json file if you have that script or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually running the custom script, so it needs to be run in a different way:

```
pm2 start npm run start:dev
```

Whenever you add any custom script `npm run scriptname` is the command to follow. If you want to know more about it, check [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script).

Also, it should be a part of the script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development npm start",
    "start:dev": "npm start --watch",
    "start:debug": "npm start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
  },
```

Comment: I ran your script and got this error ` Script not found: C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\xx\back\xx\gateway\run`

Comment: The error is with the gateway that you are adding as a part of the command. I wanted to see the package.json file and how are you running the command.

Comment: It seems you have something wrong with the command itself.

Comment: I have added my package.json script. Without pm2 I use `yarn start:dev`

Comment: I don't see `pm2`, why don't you directly run `npm run build:dev`? Also, it seems the nodemon is not installed properly. There is something that is causing the issue and you have to add it here so that I can help you.

Comment: I have 9 subgraphs and want to use pm2 to restart all at the same time when needed

Comment: Can you add more details to the error as it is difficult now to make any comments without more information?

Answer (score 4):

You can use following way to run the script :

```
pm2 start npm --name "your-app-name" -- run "start:dev"
```

Answer (score 4):

Only for who run NextJs.

should create deploy.json file:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "dicom-interactive",
            "script": "./node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
            "args": "start",
            "env": {
                "PORT": "3000",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

run

```
pm2 start deploy.json
```